# .Net Mvc Controller receives request from an image tag's angular expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have isolated that:

```
<img class="prof-pic" src="{{ item.profilePicImgTag }}" />
```

is triggering the same controller/view to receive another request! Before angular converts the {{ }} expression, my controller receives another request, with the friendlyUrlTitle value is the unparsed angular expression! How can I avoid this?

My route is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "UsersFriendlyUrlLandingPad",
                "user/{id}/{Username}",
                new { controller = "users", action = "Details", ID = UrlParameter.Optional, userName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and my controller action:

```
public virtual ActionResult Details(int id, string friendlyUrlTitle)
        {
            Node node = ICtrlHelper.IDataAccessHelper().Node.FindById(id);
            int theNumViews = node.ViewsNum;
            if (node == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(friendlyUrlTitle)) && (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(node.FriendlyUrlTitle)))
            {
                if (friendlyUrlTitle.ToLower() != node.FriendlyUrlTitle.ToLower())
                {
                    return RedirectPermanent(node.GetFullyQualifiedUrl());
                }
            }

            node.ViewsNum = node.ViewsNum + 1;
            ICtrlHelper.IDataAccessHelper().SaveChanges();

            NodeDetailVm vm = new NodeDetailVm(id, ICtrlHelper);
            ViewData["primaryContainerCssClass"] = "width1260";
            return View(Views.Details, vm);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, this question should remain as it's a good reference for others though.

Solution is to use ng-src attribute on the image instead of src

Comment: To add to this... It's likely that the browser is sending the request based on the `src` attribute before any of the JavaScript if even parsed.  Angular may change the `src` a moment later, but not until after the standard HTML was loaded and parsed.